# Music store - Is it safe to edit tags of music purchased on Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, tagging, mp3-tag

Is it safe to tamper with tags of files in `~/.ubuntuone/Purchased from Ubuntu One`, if the folder is synced locally ?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally safe to edit the tags, but doing so will result in files being resynchronized to everywhere you are syncing them.

Comment: I edited the tags for one mp3 file. On the ubuntu one web, under 'My Music' i see the new version when the current view is 'Songs'. But the Artists and Albums view show the former values of artist/title/album.

Comment: Then please file a bug about that, at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+reportbug and specify what is wrong, preferably including screen captures showing the problem (you can crop them to hide extra info you don't want to share, if necessary).

Comment: Today I checked again, and all listings are up to date !